# How to change(set) Create a PayPal account to Pay with my credit or debit card in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

**How to change (set) Create a PayPal account  to Pay with my credit or debit card in paypal using paypal**

Answer (score 0):

This would be set during checkout.  You can click a link to adjust the Funding Source after you've logged in an are reviewing the order at PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for Replay but i don't gating how can adjust.